# Нужна ли запятая, придаточное?

Tags: пунктуация

В Крыму есть указание, с украинцев деньги не брать. Придаточное ли? И запятая нужна?

Answer (score 1):

> *В Крыму есть указание, с украинцев деньги не брать.*
>
> Придаточное ли?

В этом предложении нет ни подчинительных союзов, ни союзных слов. Потому не может быть придаточных.

> И запятая нужна?

Нет, запятая не нужна. Возможен такой вариант:

***В Крыму есть указание: с украинцев деньги не брать.***

Comment: но ведь от одной части предложения другому можно задать вопрос : какое указание? разве нет?

Comment: _но ведь от одной части предложения другому можно задать вопрос : какое указание?_ === Конечно, можно. И можно вообще обойтись без знаков препинания внутри предложения, немного перестроив его: _В Крыму есть **указание не брать** деньги с украинцев_. Но в приведённом Вами варианте сочетание _"указание с украинцев"_ вносит некую двусмысленность в прочтение. Потому я и предложил двоеточие.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Двоеточие или тире, БСП:**  В Крыму есть указание: с украинцев деньги не брать. В Крыму есть указание –  деньги с украинцев  не брать.

Сравнить: Руководители всех театров Москвы получили строгое указание ― не брать к себе ни одного таганковского артиста.

В пользу двоеточия или тире говорит инверсия сочетания "не брать деньги с украинцев", которая способствует постановке пояснительной паузы.

**2) Запятую ставить нельзя, для сравнения:** В Крыму есть указание о том, чтобы с украинцев деньги не брать (**СПП**).

3) **Нет знаков, инфинитив в роли несогласованного определения** (при другой структуре предложения): Указание не брать с украинцев деньги  поступило позже.

Comment: А без знаков препинания можно обойтись здесь?

Comment: В Крыму есть указание с украинцев деньги не брать. Допустим, мы хотим обойтись без запятой, то есть остановиться на варианте несогласованного определения в сочетании "указание (какое?)  не брать".  Но в заданном варианте  эти слова находятся на расстоянии,   да еще структура предложения явно делится паузой на две части.  Поэтому при отсутствии знака и паузы получается некорректный набор слов, требующий какой-то перестройки. (Многие считают, что в русском языке свободный порядок слов, но свобода эта "мнимая" - каждое слово в предложении должно быть на своем месте).